# Are there any known W[3] or W[3]-hard problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, parameterized-complexity

We are currently working on a variant of domination parameter and we have shown that it is in W[3] with regard to parameterized complexity. To show it is W[3]-complete, we must show the problem is W[3] hard i.e, reduce an already known W[3] hard problem to ours. But unlike W[1] and W[2], where many famous problems are proved those classes, surprisingly we have not come across a single problem that is W[3] hard and not even in just W[3]. Of course there is the general W[t] case which we can go for, but any result for W[3] in particular would help a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few examples in the answer to [Natural complete problems in higher levels of the W-hierarchy](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25727/). In particular, the W[3]-complete problem **$p$-HYPERGRAPH-(NON)-DOMINATING-SET** may be useful for your proof.

Given that the linked question is now almost 6 years old, you'd perhaps expect some more examples to pop up by now. However, I couldn't find anything concrete in a quick literature search. The closest thing I could find was  *Separating sets of strings by finding matching patterns is almost always hard* (2017) by Lancia et al., where they **conjecture** that the problem they call **PATTERN IDENTIFICATION** is W[3]-complete for a particular parameter, but this conjecture is probably not very useful for your proof. I do note that I'm not an expert in this field, so there may be some more recent results out there I simply wasn't able to find.

Comment: Indeed after so many years, somehow not many problems have been proved in this category .. Even i'll keep searching and post here in case i find something .. This is the first result on W[3] that i came across .. So thank you!

Comment: @VenugopalK You're welcome. Note that you can also choose to [accept an answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if it has been useful to you.